# Can I create a type, typedef or using statement that results in a different type if instantiated a second time or more?

Tags: c++, templates

Suppose I have a class that evaluates some computationally intensive function:

```
class Value
{
private:
  int eval()
  {
    mCached = ExpensiveOperation();
    return mCached;
  }
  static int mCached;
};
```

Now suppose that `Value` is actually some template expression, like `Plus<1, Multiply<2, 3>>` or something to that effect. It may itself be nested and might appear multiple times as part of a larger expression.

I don't know what the expression is, but I *do* know, based on its position in the expression, which instantiation of it (if there are multiple instantiations of exactly the same type) will be evaluated first.

I want to memoize the result for subsequently instantiated types, such that they are not evaluated more than once each time the expression is evaluated.

The *easy* way of achieving this is store the cached results in some sort of `hash_map` or to use singletons which check whether a static member is evaluated, but heap allocation and lookups are expensive, plus we already know the types at compile time *and* we know which instance is going to be evaluated first, so why not prepare the memoization at compile time as well?

What if we had something like a `Cached` type, which simply pulled the result from the first class of the same type:

```
template <typename Expression>
class Cached
{
  int eval()
  {
    return Expression::mCached; // cheap!
  }
};
```

The problem is that I now have to remember to place `Cached` everywhere if an expression is repeated!

```
// Inefficient but nice expression:
Add<Multiply<2, 3>, Multiply<2, 3>>

// Efficient but ugly expression
Add<Multiply<2, 3>, Cached<2, 3>>;
```

How can I create an expression that looks like the "inefficient but nice expression" yet still automatically generates a `Cached` type?

Comment: Is the computation result always the same for the same type ? Or may it differ according to some external parameters in each run ?

Comment: @YochaiTimmer it can differ each run, but _in_ each run it is the same for all instantiations of the same type.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question correctly, you can just use a local static variable to store the result of the expensive calculation.

```
class Value
{
private:
  int eval()
  {
    static int mCached = ExpensiveOperation();
    return mCached;
  }
};
```

Comment: Note that a local static variable is a thread safe singleton (in C++11), so this answer is strictly both simpler and better than the Lazy Singleton solution in 11, in 03 it is still a singleton but no longer thread safe.

Answer (score 0):

You can look at the cached value as a Lazy Singleton object.
This way it will only be calculated once per type.

```
int eval()
  {
    if (mCached == nullptr)
    {
       //Lock here
       if (mCached == nullptr) //double check after lock
       {
          int tempValue = ExpensiveOperation();
          mCached.reset(new int(tempValue));
       }
    }
    return *mCached.get();
  }
static uinque_ptr<int> mCached;
```

Comment: What is the point of the `new`?

Comment: Double checked locking doesn't work in C++.

Comment: It's just pseudo code. In c++11 you can make it safe.